# Spring Boot Security OAuth2 with Form Login

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am following [Part V of Getting Started with Spring Boot Security](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_sso_with_oauth2_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_v) to secure my RESTful microservices.

The simple flow that I intend to implement is:-

1. If unauthenticated, the user is redirected to a custom login page at
   say '/login'.
2. User provides his credentials.
3. On successful authentication user is redirected to home page
   ('/home'). I should be able to access my REST endpoint (behind a
   Zuul Proxy Server) after providing the access token in the request.

The Getting Started guide in the above mentioned link uses Basic Auth and dummy user configured in .properties or .yml file.

This is how I tried with my configuration:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("acme").secret("acmesecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password").scopes("openid")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous()").checkTokenAccess("isAnonymous()")
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

}



@Configuration
@Import({ OptoSoftSecurityServiceConfig.class })
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService; // backed by MongoDB

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().disable().formLogin();// disabled basic auth and configured to use dafault Spring Security form login.
    }
}
```

Hitting the [authorization endpoint](http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://example.com) redirects me to 'http://localhost:9999/uaa/login' with error message as:-

```
<oauth>
<error_description>
Full authentication is required to access this resource
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

**PROBLEM**

1. How can I configure Authorization Server to use UserDetailsService
   instead of static user and use Form Login instead of Basic Auth.
2. How can I configure Auto Approval while using 'authorization_code'
   as the grant type?
3. Is it mandatory for /oauth/authorize endpoint to be protected by
   Basic Auth? Why 'Full authentication is required' to access the
   /oauth/authorize' endpoint. I believe we do not know who is the user
   before this endpoint. The user can only be identified once he has
   been authenticated using valid credentials which comes after form
   login.

Answer (score 4):

Finally got it working. The git repo in the mentioned blog already had this thing configured. Turns out it was pretty straight forward.

This is what worked for me (I have also configured auto approval to true):-

```
**
 * @author kumar
 *
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthenticationServerApplication {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthenticationServerApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.formLogin().permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();//.and().userDetailsService(yourCustomerUserDetailsService);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory().withClient("acme").secret("acmesecret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password").scopes("openid")
                    .autoApprove(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        }

    }

}
```

application.yml:-

```
  security:
      user:
        password: password
    server:
      port: 9999
      context-path: /uaa
```

Comment: Could you please provide me the git repo url for this example ?

Comment: Hi Kumar, the github repo is not found. Could I have the source code ?

Comment: @tranceholic You can either checkout mine: https://github.com/ksambhav/trueyes or Daye Syer's Spring guide: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2